# Anyway of being Notified of a Magento 2 Update without logging in the Admin Panel

Tags: magento2, upgrade, version

Say I have 2 sites that I don't really logon to the admin panel all that often, is there anyway to notify me of any updates to magento? e.g. RSS feed, Email ?

I heard of a potential rss feed from a host computer but i have no idea how I would set something like this up.

I'm surprised it isnt a feature that is more common knowledge as I imagine a large amount of people have several sites to manage at once.

Failing that, is there anyway to auto update ?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever magento updates version or provide security upate you get message from the magento right in your backoffic/adminpanel. Its automaticly keep you update about version and security updates. i.e

[image]

Comment: Is there anyway of getting an email so I don't have to login each time to see notifications?

Comment: You may create/registor at magento official site https://account.magento.com/customer/account/login to  get latest news and updates directly in your email.